# Monotonic/Vixie-style DST interpretation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm looking for an JavaScript algorithm to convert local calendar date-times into UTC milliseconds since Unix epoch (or to `Date` objects representing the same). A typical, and often useful, way to do this for some relative calendar date `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.zzz` is:

```
# Close, but not quite monotonic
(new Date(YYYY, MM-1, DD, hh, mm, ss, zzz)).getTime()
```

JavaScript implementations have their ways of dealing with DST (read: daylight saving time, summer time, your own locale's equivalent as necessary), and unfortunately they don't work for the application at hand, which instead calls for local time that is monotonic (but may be distorted if necessary).

The conversion must be monotonic in the sense that for two relative calendar dates (i.e. timezone-ignorant, DST-ignorant) A and B, the conversion, a function C, is such that

```
If A is strictly earlier than B then C(A) ≤ C(B)
If A is simultaneous to B then       C(A) = C(B)
If A is strictly later than B then   C(A) ≥ C(B)
```

(This doesn't refer to monotonicity in the sense that successive calls to a time-getting function are strictly non-decreasing—this application has no concept of the *current* time and doesn't need anything like that.)

I've started working on an implementation of my own, but it's threatening to be complicated, and I think perhaps someone else has better ideas.

The questions are:

- Has this already been implemented?
- If not, is there a saner way to implement this than what I've outlined below?

  - Do the discontinuity-finding heuristics work for all known DSTs worldwide?

### JavaScript `Date`'s behavior

The following represent the corner cases for DST in the US in 2012. The values are experimental results from Firefox. Here, let the function C represent the result of creating a `Date` object using the given local date and time, then using the `getTime()` method to retrieve the UTC milliseconds.

- Skipped hour: On 2012-03-11, the start date of DST, the hour starting 02:00 is skipped in local time: The minute following 01:59 is 03:00. In Firefox, a later input time may result in an earlier resolved time; e.g. 01:45 < 02:15, but C(01:45) > C(02:15), so the scale is not monotonic.
- Doubled hour: On 2012-11-04, the end date of DST, the hour starting 01:00 occurs twice in local time: The minute following 01:59 daylight time is 01:00 standard time, then the minute following 01:59 standard time is 02:00 standard time. In Firefox, C(01:30) corresponds to the later repetition, 01:30 standard time.

  - This does not break monotonicity, as long as the resolving behavior is guaranteed to favor the later time. (I don't have documentation of this guarantee, but perhaps it follows from some language in ECMA-262.)

### Required/preferred behavior

Here, let the function C represent a conversion with the desired behavior.

- Skipped hour: The date for a skipped minute should be resolved to the first following unskipped minute. For example, on the DST start date, 02:15, 02:30, and 02:45 would resolve to the next unskipped minute, 03:00; in other words, C(02:15) = C(02:30) = C(02:45) = C(03:00).

  - Unskipped times would remain untransformed: Compare 01:45 < 02:15 < 02:45 < 03:15 to C(01:45) < C(02:15) = C(02:45) < C(03:15).
- Doubled hour: The date for a minute occurring multiple times should be resolved to the first occurrence only; e.g. 01:30 on the end date of DST would be resolved to 01:30 daylight time rather than standard time, since that is the earlier of the two.

  - Same as before, except that the earlier time is guaranteed.

These rules are loosely based on those of Vixie cron. However, this application doesn't deal with a concept of *current* time and thus doesn't have the state it would need to watch the clock for time changes. It would need some other way to determine if and when times will be skipped or doubled.

Incidentally, as an additional requirement, the implementation must not assume that it is running in a US locale; it needs to work internationally and, wherever possible, use detection over configuration.

### Implementation thoughts

One thing I thought might work for detecting whether a date falls into a discontinuity would be to test the width of the span of the local dates ±1 calendar day from the date. If the difference between the UTC times of the two dates is less than or greater than 48 hours, it would imply that some time had been skipped or doubled, respectively.

- If skipped, we might further determine whether the given time itself is skipped if, after converting to UTC and back, the `hh:mm:ss.zzz` reads differently. If so, the time is resolved to the first minute after the discontinuity.
- If doubled, we might determine the range of all times in the later repetition. If the given time falls within the later repetition, it is reverted to the earlier; otherwise, it is left alone.

Both of these could require the exact location of the discontinuities, which could for example be accomplished with a binary search bounded by the ±1 dates.

This heuristic could fail for multiple reasons; though I'm of the impression that they are unlikely, summer time rules are strange and inconsistent worldwide:

- If it's possible for more than one discontinuity in either direction to occur within the same 3 calendar days. (In the US, there are two per year, months apart. I doubt anyplace adjusts any amount greater than, say, four hours.)

  - If the discontinuities are complementary, they may not be detected in the first place.
  - In any case, a simple search would make the assumption that there is only one discontinuity within the range.
- If it's possible for a single discontinuity to account for a duration of (nearly) 3 calendar days. (In the US, each discontinuity accounts for one hour. I'm fairly certain that summer time adjustment is never on the order of days anywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An implementation consistent with **Required/preferred behavior** above, at least for the current USA rules](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~psmay/+junk/coffee-clock-face-resolver/view/2/clock-face-resolve.coffee), is now available. Overall, the mechanism isn't terribly inefficient. In the worst case (a skipped minute), it's O(lg n) where n is the number of minutes of change between summer and winter (60 where I live), and in all other cases, it's O(1).

- The input is a "face" (a calendar date and time ignorant of DST).
- The output is a `Date` with its local face set based on the input face.

  - If the input face represents exactly one local date, the output `Date` is the same as if the stats of the face were passed to the `Date` constructor.
  - If the input face represents zero local dates (due to DST skipping forward), the output `Date` reflects the first minute following the skip.
  - If the input face represents two local dates (due to DST repeating), the output `Date` reflects the earlier of the two.

Notes on the implementation:

- The `.getTimezoneOffset()` method is used to determine whether two dates are on opposite sides of a discontinuity.
- The offset before any discontinuity a face might be near is found by retrieving the offset of a `Date` 24 local hours prior to that face.
- The face is converted to a `Date` by passing its stats to the `Date` constructor to be interpreted locally.
- If the local face of the converted `Date` is not the same as the input face, this face is not directly representable in local time; it has been skipped.

  - The converted `Date` is treated as invalid.
  - The timezone offset following the discontinuity is determined by retrieving the offset of a `Date` 24 local face hours after the input face.
  - The difference between the offsets before and after the discontinuity is found. From that amount of time *before* the input face to that amount of time *after* (which should by definition both be representable as local dates), a binary search is used to locate the first minute after the discontinuity. A `Date` representing this minute is the output.
- If the local face of the converted `Date` is the same as the input face,

  - If the converted `Date` has the pre-discontinuity offset, it is correct.
  - This includes any face not near a DST change; if there is no discontinuity, then all times for that day share the same offset.
  - Even if the face is in a doubled time, the early interpretation is the correct one. (Whether this can happen may be implementation-dependent.)
  - If the converted `Date` occurs after the discontinuity,
  - It is correct if it is at a time later than the discontinuity by at least the offset difference.
  - If it is in the range of time from the discontinuity through one offset difference afterward, it is in the later interpretation of a doubled time. The correct date is found by subtracting the offset difference, yielding the earlier interpretation.
  - A `Date` is determined to be in this range if a `Date` that is earlier by one offset difference has the early offset. Since the converted `Date` has the late offset, it is determined that the discontinuity happened more recently than that.